# How to use WCF client within a for loop in C#

Tags: wcf

I am using a WCF Client to make service calls. I am making multiple calls to the same endpoint within a For-loop, I have specific question on whether I should be reinitializing the client inside for loop every time(with open() and close()) or Should I be doing it outside of loop? Also, How do I handle the exception scenario where the client gets aborted and I have to continue making calls further.

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% convenced if its a duplicate question.

[How to handle WCF connection when calling method in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895770/how-to-handle-wcf-connection-when-calling-method-in-loop)
and [multiple calls to WCF service method in a loop (using the same proxy object) causing timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629467/multiple-calls-to-wcf-service-method-in-a-loop-using-the-same-proxy-object-cau)

However, you do not need to reinitialise the client proxy object inside the loop. In your for loop just call the WCF service method.

For the exceptions, I would wrap the WCF Service method call inside the loop into try-catch block and another one to wrap from outside the loop or the method calling this one.

Note: Its only when the the WCF service method is called the conneciton is attamptted to be established and the message is sent across the wire. So captureing the method call inside the loop is recomended.